# Using django form fieldsets in form.as_p

Tags: django, forms, fieldset

I'm trying to sectorize a plain forms.Form (not an Admin form, not a ModelForm) into [fieldsets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset) (not formsets).

I have the inner class `Meta` with a `fieldsets` attribute:

```
class Meta:
    fieldsets = (
       {'Input Parameters': (
               u'par_cd4Q', 
               u'par_cd4A',
               u'par_cd4QI1', 
               u'par_vPnB1', 
               u'par_vPB1',
               u'par_Tmax',
               u'par_sT',
               u'par_r',
               u'par_xi',
               u'par_muQ')}, 
       {'Simulation Arguments': (
               u'arg_r', 
               u'arg_m')}
    )
```

But in the template using `form.as_p` renders just a plain form, without any section.

What am I missing. Is this functionality only available in the admin interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will most likely need to use something like [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this, I don't believe that functionality is built into the normal form rendering.